# Determine the mass of the solid, provided its density at a point $P(x,y,z)$ is proportional to the distance from the $XY$ plane.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, volume

I am trying to solve the following problem*

> A solid can be described in three-dimensional space by the following system of inequalities:**
> $$\begin{cases}
> x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1\\
> z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
> \end{cases}$$
> Determine the mass of the solid, provided its density at a point $P(x,y,z)$ is proportional to the distance from the $XY$ plane.

I came out with the following triple integral

$$k\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} rz dz dr dθ. $$

but the problem is that I got zero where I calculed the integral because
\begin{align*}
M &= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \frac{1}{2}rz^2 \right]_{r}^{\sqrt{1 - r^2}} \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{2}r(1 - r^2) - \frac{1}{2}r^3 \right) \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[ \frac{1}{4}r^2 - \frac{1}{4}r^4 \right]_{0}^{1} \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} 0 \, d\theta \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Did I do something wrong and where? Thanks!

Comment: When $r$ is close to $1$ we have $r > \sqrt{1-r^2}$, so the limits of integration of the inner integral are problematic.

Comment: So, how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can handle the cases $r^2 < 1/2$ and $r^2 > 1/2$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1\\
z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{cases}\implies r^2\leq z^2\leq 1-r^2\implies r^2\leq \frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore your integral should be
$$\begin{align*}
M &=k\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\color{blue}{1/{\sqrt{2}}}}\int_{r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} rz dz dr d\theta\\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\color{blue}{1/{\sqrt{2}}}} \left[ \frac{1}{2}rz^2 \right]_{r}^{\sqrt{1 - r^2}} \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\color{blue}{1/{\sqrt{2}}}} \left( \frac{1}{2}r(1 - r^2) - \frac{1}{2}r^3 \right) \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[ \frac{1}{4}r^2 - \frac{1}{4}r^4 \right]_{0}^{\color{blue}{1/{\sqrt{2}}}} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{k}{4} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}} \right) \, d\theta =\color{blue}{\frac{\pi k}{8}}.
\end{align*}$$